# How could I generate questions True/False from a given text with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

I would like to generate questions True/False from a given text.

For example:

Text:

"Jim's dog was very hairy and smelled like wet newspaper"

Questions:

-"Jim's dog was very hairy and smelled like a rose" T/F

-"Jim does not have a dog" T/F

Comment: That's Question Answering.. that's not an easy task.

Comment: @Anwarvic what about selecting randomly some sentences and negate them?

Answer (score 0):

This could be easily done with the input command in python.

```
is_smelly = input("Jim's dog was very hairy and smelled like a rose? Y/N").lower()
if is_smelly[0] == 'y':
    print('Nope')
has_dog = input("Jim does not have a dog Y/N")
if has_dog[0] == 'y':
    print('Nope')
```

Kind of rinse and repeat after this. For every question you have, you could use yes or no values for booleans ( e.g true or false ). Then when the user gives you the answer, you can store it in that variable and then use it in an if statment to decide what happens next.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion , true/false can be generated in two ways.

First way is to take out the modal verb from sentence and put it at the start of the sentence and add ? at the end of sentence. The other way is to negate the sentence.